How to change the coordinate system for all p5 objects (including the slider)
With this code I make a frame with x going from -25 to 25, y going from -25 to 25. x is pointing rightwards and y upwards.
type gridRange={
    xrange:{
        min: number,
        max: number,
    },
    yrange:{
        min: number,
        max: number,
    }
};



const setCoordinateSystem =(r :gridRange,p : p5) =>{
    let xscalingCoeff = window.innerWidth / (r.xrange.max - r.xrange.min);
    let yscalingCoeff = window.innerHeight / (r.yrange.max - r.yrange.min) * -1; // MAKE y points upwards
    let xcenter = r.xrange.max ;
    let ycenter = r.xrange.min ; //NOT AN ERROR!
    p.scale(xscalingCoeff, yscalingCoeff);
    p.translate(xcenter, ycenter);

};


function draw(p: p5): void {
  p.background(255)

 const r: gridRange = {
        xrange: {
            min: -25,
            max: 25,
        },
        yrange: {
            min: -25,
            max: 25,
        },
    };

    setCoordinateSystem(r,p)
}

If I add
 p.text('test', -25, 0);

In draw() I get my text to be placed where I asked (on the extreme left of my frame and vertically exactly in the middle). That is not completely true but this is another question.
Now I want to do the same thing with a slider, but the slider gets the wanted place only if I give the coordinates in pixels and with y pointing backwards.
I have to enter:
 slider = p.createSlider(0, 1, 0.5, 0.01); // these parameters don't give position. just the posible value of my slider. Not important in this case
 slider.position(0, 1400);

to have my slider at the same position as my text.
